# Why this T-SQL query doesn't work in Synapse?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parquet, azure-synapse

I am testing Synapse. I tried this query

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '<path to the parquet file>',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

But I get the following error. How can I solve it?

> Parse error at line: 4, column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That type of query would work in the serverless SQL pool, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset) on `OPENROWSET`.  It would not work in a dedicated SQL pool.

If you are in Synapse Studio, try changing the **Connect to** option to **Built-in**, which is the serverless engine.  Optionally create a database to store objects like external data sources, external tables and views in:

[image: Synapse Studio]

Another easy way to generate a working `OPENROWSET` statement would be via Synapse Studio > Data hub (the little cylinder on the right), Linked > double-click your datalake to navigate to the parquet file you want to query > right-click it > SELECT TOP 100 ...

[image: Synapse Studio 2]